# Android save variable in runtime

Tags: java, android, cookies

For my project i'm making calls to an API, but you have to be authenticated. So I want to save the cookie from the first request so I can re use that cookie. How can I save the cookie only for as long as the application is active. I don't want to save the cookie into internal storage because of the security. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use a singleton with static variables which saves the cookie data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Shared Preferences and remove prefrences in onBackPressed of your last activity.

```
SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

mPreferences.edit().putString("MY_COOKIES", mStringCookies).commit();
```

in your last activity override method:

```
onBackPressed() {

SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

mPreferences.edit().remove("MY_COOKIES").commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Give [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) a try.

Store the cookie when you receive it and delete it in `onStop()` of your `Activity`or `Fragment`.

Comment: I will see if this works. But now I have to delete every cookie manually. Isn't there anything else which deletes for me?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                    editor.putInt("Cookiename","Value");
                                    editor.apply();
```